# Android restore original project files from compiler-generated fiels

Tags: android, decompiling, recover

I made a huge mistake while creating my git repository and the /src folder has not been saved.

All i have is a bunch of .class files that correspond to my original code. If I try to decompile the.class file I can see the original code (at least I haven´t lost anything)

The issue is that for a single class, p.e. Helper.class,

it has 3 different files:

Helper$1.class
Helper$2.class
Helper.class

I was wondering if there's any tool that could help me in order to merge this 3 files in a single one.

Thanks a lot.